# Differentiability of scalar function

Tags: analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb R→\mathbb R$ be a continuous function, with $f(0)=0$. Let 
                        $F(x,y)=xf(y)+yf(x)$.

Analize if $F$ is differentiable at the origin.$$$$

I've proved that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)$ exist and that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=0=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)$. If $F$ is differentiable at the origin, then the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac {|F(x,y)-(F(0,0)+<∇F(0,0),(x,y)>)|} {||(x,y)||}$=$0$ This limit is equal to $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac {|xf(y)+yf(x)|} {||(x,y)||}$. I couldn't go beyond this. Both iterated limits give $0$, but I know this is not sufficient to affirm that the original limit is $0$. Could anyone give me a hint?

I add something that I've just came up with:
I can express $xf(y)+yf(x)$ as $<(x,y),(f(y),f(x)>$. By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $|<(x,y),(f(y),f(x)>|\le||(x,y)||||(f(y),f(x))||$. Then, $$$$ $0\le\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac {|xf(y)+yf(x)|} {||(x,y)||}\le\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac {||(x,y)||||(f(y),f(x))||} {||(x,y)||}$. The last expression is $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac {||(x,y)||||(f(y),f(x))||} {||(x,y)||}=\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} ||(f(y),f(x))||=||(f(0),f(0))||=0$. By the squeeze theorem, I can conclude that  $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac {|F(x,y)-(F(0,0)+<∇F(0,0),(x,y)>)|} {||(x,y)||}$=$0$, which means that $F$ is differentiable at the point $(0,0)$. $$$$Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

In multivariable calculus the existence of partial derivatives does not guarantee the derivabilty of the function itself.

The function is differentiable at origin if $\Delta f(0,0)=A\Delta x+B\Delta y+o\left(\sqrt{(\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2}\right)$, where neither $A$ nor $B$ depend on $(\Delta x,\Delta y)$.

$$\Delta F(0,0)=F(\Delta x,\Delta y)-F(0,0)=F(\Delta x, \Delta y)=\Delta xf(\Delta y)+\Delta yf(\Delta x)$$

The answer is ready now.

Comment: Thanks for the help. To be honest, I don't understand what you wrote, maybe I don't understand the notation. I could think of something else, I've added it to my original post.